# Trying to get the arrow button to the right of a textbox inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

I can't seem to be able to get my button positioned to the right, of a textbox inside a DIV. Below is capture of the problem and I've provided a capture of the expected end result:

[image]

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Here is the HTML markup & CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#recent {
    width: 175px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.search_field {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 175px;
}

.search_field input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#btn_arrow {
    border: none;
    width: 15px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div class="search_field">
<input id="fileno" type="text">
<input type="button" value="&#9660;" id="btn_arrow">
</div>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
<ul id="recent"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `position:absolute;`

```
#btn_arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.search_field
{
    position: relative;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ssby63y/)

```css
#btn_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.search_field {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #recent {
      width: 175px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }
    .search_field {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 175px;
    }
    .search_field input {
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #btn_arrow {
      border: none;
      width: 15px;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="search_field">
    <input id="fileno" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="&#9660;" id="btn_arrow">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search">
  <ul id="recent"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reduce the width of `.search_field input` to less than 100%. Giving 100% width will span it across the whole area.

http://jsfiddle.net/gu02emyd/3/

Add this

```
.search_field input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 88%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `width: calc(100% - 15px);` and `float:left;` on `.search_field input`

```css
#recent {
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.search_field {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 175px;
}
.search_field input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 15px); // using calc to do 100% minus the width of the button
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left; // floating left so button moves up
}
#btn_arrow {
  border: none;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_field">
  <input id="fileno" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="&#9660;" id="btn_arrow">
</div>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
<ul id="recent"></ul>
```